# Elasticsearch clustering configuration in node.js

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to setup elastic-search clustering for my node.js application. For testing i have 2 Virtual Machines(ubuntu) running , in that in 1st machine i modified the `elasticsearch.yml` as following

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: "naodename1" , also ES running in port 9200
```

and in the second machine as follows:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: "node_1" , ES running in port 9400
```

I stopped machine 1 ES , now i connected from my node app, data is coming, Ithink from machine 2, so clustering works here.

But when i create an index in machine1 that should replicate to machine2 ES.
 I created a sample index in machine1 as follows:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9400/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
"user" : "kimchy",
"post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
"message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}'
```

Now i tried to search using machine1 ES as follows:

```
http://192.168.1.109:9200/twitter/_search?&q=*
```

I am receiving error:

```
"Index missing exception". Whether i am missing any configuration. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: you are putting your document on your localhost host and searching a distant machine (192.168.1.109) ?!?

Comment: @eliasah  Thanks for your time.. I have configured my local ip as 192.168.1.109

Comment: and how do you have a cluster running on two different ports?

Comment: @eliasah  Actually its 2 different oracle virtual machines(ubuntu box), so i have 2 ES instances running in 2 diferent machines

Comment: ok so first, your question is not node.js related, second your cluster setup it a total mayhem!

Comment: @eliasah K. I tried a different approach. I have 2 machines running ES in defult port 9200. Machine1 ip is 192.168.1.109 and 2nd machine ip is 192.168.1.107, Having cluster name as same, But the index created is not replicating??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77618/discussion-between-eliasah-and-subburaj).